# How to output a specific paragraph based on a pattern?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, text

I have a sample file below:

```
# This is a test file. This is a test file. This is a test file  
This is a test file. This is a test file. This is a test file.  
This is a test file.

# Need to output just this paragraph.Need to output just this paragraph.  
Need to output just this paragraph TOO. Need to output just this paragraph.  
Need to output just this paragraph.
```

I need to output just the second paragraph starting from "#" till the last sentence in the paragraph.

How do I grep and output based on the pattern? Say if the file has more paragraphs, and I would like to output the paragraph which contains the word "TOO".

Answer (score 2):

If the paragraphs are empty line separated:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' /TOO/
```

An empty record separator (`RS`) means *paragraph mode* where records are separated by sequences of empty lines.

If they are `#` separated:

```
awk -v RS='#' '/TOO/ {print RS $0}'
```

or

```
pcregrep -Mo '#[^#]*?TOO[^#]*'
```

- `-M` for multiline `grep`
- `-o` to output the matched portion only

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -00ne 'print if /TOO/'
```

- `-00` means paragraph mode (records are separated by one or more empty lines).